# How to set text of an AppCompatSpinner? Please see details

Tags: java, android, android-studio, datepicker, android-spinner

I have an `AppCompatSpinner` whose entries I have saved in `strings.xml` file like this:

```
<string-array name="startDayList">
        <item>Today</item>
        <item>Tomorrow</item>
        <item>Pick a day..</item>
</string-array>
```

After specifying this as AppCompatSpinner's entries using this code: `android:entries="@array/startDayList"`, the title or the text which is getting shown on the AppCompatSpinner is `Today`.

Here, when the user selects `Pick a day..` entry, he is shown a `DatePicker` and is allowed to choose a day/date. Here's how (case 2):

```
startDaySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

                DateFormat currentDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
                startDayString = currentDateFormat.format(new Date());

                switch (i) {
                    case 0:

                        startDayString = currentDateFormat.format(new Date());
                        break;

                    case 1:

                        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

                        calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);
                        Date tomorrow = calendar.getTime();

                        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
                        startDayString = dateFormat.format(tomorrow);
                        break;

                    case 2:
                        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                        mYearStartE = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                        mMonthStartE = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                        mDayStartE = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

                        DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(PostSportRequest.this,
                                new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                                    @Override
                                    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                                                          int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

                                        startDayString = dayOfMonth + "-" + (monthOfYear + 1) + "-" + year;

                                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "startDayString: " + startDayString, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                    }
                                }, mYearStartE, mMonthStartE, mDayStartE);
                        datePickerDialog.show();
                        break;
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

            }
        });
```

This code save the date chosen in a the `startDayString` string, but the text of the `AppCompatSpinner` remains to be set as `Pick a day..`

So, I want to know that how can I set the text/title of the spinner as the day/date chosen by the user and not `Pick a day..`

Please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set text on the items view:

```
    startDaySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(final AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {


            DateFormat currentDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
            startDayString = currentDateFormat.format(new Date());

            switch (i) {
                case 0:

                    startDayString = currentDateFormat.format(new Date());
                    break;

                case 1:

                    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

                    calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);
                    Date tomorrow = calendar.getTime();

                    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
                    startDayString = dateFormat.format(tomorrow);
                    break;

                case 2:
                    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                    mYearStartE = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                    mMonthStartE = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                    mDayStartE = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

                    DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(PurchaseActivity.this,
                            new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                                                      int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

                                    startDayString = dayOfMonth + "-" + (monthOfYear + 1) + "-" + year;

                                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "startDayString: " + startDayString, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                    TextView mTextView = (TextView) adapterView.getSelectedView();
                                    mTextView.setText(startDayString);
                                }
                            }, mYearStartE, mMonthStartE, mDayStartE);
                    datePickerDialog.show();
                    break;
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

        }
    });
```